# Resusing common functionality across two VS2013 applications

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-8, visual-studio-2013

We are working on a project where in we need to develop two separate windows 8 store apps. Apps need to use MVVP pattern. Although the apps are more than 50% functionality different such as views, view-models, classes etc. 
We don't want these functionality to be copy-pasted for different application. We need the approach to design a solution so that we can have a maximum and effective reuse of common functionality.

- one option could be using a single project and two different targets (binaries). Is there any way in VS2013 by which we can have two targets differentiated by some preprocessors by altering the build settings?
- another approach can be using one solution, two separate projects and keeping set of common files as shared. Again we are not sure whether VS2013 solution allows me to do that.

Can someone please help us to decide the best approach..

Comment: Build a DLL with the common functionality?

Comment: I not sure or may sound stupid here..But is it advisable to embed views & viewModel class in a DLL?

Comment: Yes you can use View & ViewModel in DLL or you can create a third project which has common code & pass reference of that project.

Comment: @Xyroid thanks. what should be the type of the third project in this case..will it be a library linked statically/ dynamically.